# Give "Citizen Patrol" badge for flagging comments too

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, flags

The "Citizen Patrol" badge is given out for "first flagged post".  I'd suggest that this also include comments.  In other words, if a user flags a comment before ever flagging a post, you should give him the badge for flagging a comment.

Or maybe you could create a separate badge for first flagged comment (but I don't think that's really needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible, as comments aren't logged in the same way as posts.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the CP badge is only awarded for items that are Flag For Moderator Attention. Flagging it as Spam or Offensive doesn't seem to reward the badge. With that said, I don't think you should give the CP badge out for flagging comments because you don't have the "for moderator attention" option which prompts you for a reason.

**Edit**: I may have been mistaken and the CP badge is only awarded for Offensive/Spam flags and not Moderator Attention flags.

Comment: hmm.. maybe the badge is actually broken right now.  i flagged a post for moderator attention yesterday, because it was an exact duplicate and almost no one can vote to close yet on MSO.  i haven't received the badge yet..

Comment: Kip: I was having the same troubles early on that you were. It very well may be that I am backwards in what I said and the flag for moderator is the one that it doesn't work for, but I can't be sure. I just remember being very confused about this when I was first on Meta.

Comment: I believe I got CP for flagging a post as spam on SO. I've flagged for Mod Attention on MSO and never go rewarded a badge.

Comment: Ian Elliot: Then perhaps I have it backwards.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. I wondered why I didn't get the CP badge given that I've flagged several posts on SO... but I've only ever flagged for mods. Surely that's a bug & not by design though?