# Why haven't I received a tag badge and the Citizen Patrol badge?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-badges

Did the margins for the silver & gold specialty badges change recently?
I reached 400 votes for the [sql-server tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sql-server&sort=stats), but it's been ~2 days and still haven't been awarded the badge.  I gather there's a delay to make sure votes aren't reversed/etc...

On a side note, what does it take to get a Citizen Patrol badge?  I've flagged numerous things, comments and questions alike.

Comment: Unrelated: I get the impression "urban hanggliding" is sarcastic and made-up... but it sounds incredibly awesome.  Now I need to investigate the logistics of it...

Comment: @Tom: On par with base jumping - rather illegal.  Forgot my bio was populated on meta...

Comment: @OMG Not concerned about the illegality, concerned about how likely the cross-winds would be to kill you...

Comment: Don't forget not all badge awarding processes run every 5 minutes. Some like the tag badges appear to only run on every couple of days (or that's what it appeared like when I hit 400 votes for c#). Or you might actually need 401 votes!

Comment: @ChrisF: I realize that - that's why I mentioned that it's been **two days** now.  I'm at 403 now...

Comment: Gah! 404 now, so I've surpassed the 3 (assuming credited) in the CW post...

Comment: Got the badge this morning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your second question (citizen patrol badge):

You can't get it for flagging comments, as according to Jeff Atwood it's ["Not possible, as comments aren't logged in the same way as posts."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/give-citizen-patrol-badge-for-flagging-comments-too/7145#7145)

<del>And with questions/answers, you only get it for flagging as spam/offensive. Again, Jeff says it ["is only awarded for spam and offensive flags, as we moved the mod flags to another table. So if you really want it, flag spam/offensive."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/citizen-patrol-badge-not-awarded/7147#7147) (see his comment towards the bottom).</del> As of [2011-02-09](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74243/68727), "Flagging for moderator attention now counts for the Citizen Patrol badge. This change applies retroactively."

Comment: The answer you link to informs: `2011-02-09: Flagging for moderator attention now counts for the Citizen Patrol badge. This change applies retroactively.`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 3):

Votes in community wiki questions don't count towards tag badges.  Perhaps some of your 400 votes are in CW questions.

Comment: Plausible - shouldn't that be reflected in the stats page for the tag?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: FWIW, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A135152+[sql-server]+wiki%3A1 just gives one result, with three upvotes. So you're not terribly far away from the badge.

Comment: @balpha: Thx, but I've never seen rep credit from that answer, and I watched the stats page - it didn't appear to show up there either. Or it was really delayed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the stats page already omits wiki posts.