# I flagged a post but don't have citizen patrol badge?

Tags: support, badges, comment-flags, flagging-badges

Consider:

[image]

Per the above I recently flagged a post on Stack Overflow, and yet I [don't have](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569976/neubert?tab=badges) the [Citizen Patrol badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Is there something else I have to do to get that badge?

Comment: Unrelated - Will you please just click on your inbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured it out. Since this was a *not constructive* flag, and [only comments can be flagged as that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192110/get-rid-of-or-rename-the-not-constructive-comment-flag-reason), you've flagged a comment.

The Citizen Patrol badge is only awarded from flags to questions and answers, [due to the method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/give-citizen-patrol-badge-for-flagging-comments-too) in which the flags are stored in the database.